Why does the iPhone app on M1 Mac run well but crashes at launch except first time I open after restarting the Mac
I play go on the GoQuest iPhone app on my M1 Mac Mini.  The app was downloaded from the App Store on the Mac (not iphone mirroring).
I run the app, it works great.  But if I close it, it crashes at launch every subsequent time that I open it.
So whenever I restart my computer, I can use it again.
At this point I start it and I'm very careful to always minimize it and never close it. But at some point I always end up closing it.
I'm thinking that since it works again after a restart that it's not a problem with files but rather some process that the GoQuest app interacts with becomes weird but being unfamiliar with how macOS runs these iPhone apps, I haven't been able to find it.
Here is a partial crash report; only the start of it because of the limit on post size:
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: E6B1583F-AB66-4F64-A03B-F3EA3CD533FB
CrashReporter Key:   4C73C89D-D754-81CA-E621-DB60C76F9BE8
Hardware Model:      Macmini9,1
Process:             GoQuest [78282]
Path:                /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/GoQuest
Identifier:          fm.wars.GoQuest
Version:             1.5.12 (1.5.12.0)
AppStoreTools:       14E221
AppVariant:          1:MacFamily20,1:15
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           fm.wars.GoQuest [2338]

Date/Time:           2024-09-30 19:24:16.0923 -0400
Launch Time:         2024-09-30 19:24:15.2960 -0400
OS Version:          macOS 15.0 (24A335)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a25581fc
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [78282]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x19e7b4eb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19e29acd8 objc_exception_throw + 88
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19e86a5a4 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19e721140 ___forwarding___ + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19e720a60 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
5   GoQuest                                0x1009f4b40 0x1009c8000 + 183104
6   GoQuest                                0x1009f472c 0x1009c8000 + 182060
7   GoQuest                                0x1009f4674 0x1009c8000 + 181876
8   GoQuest                                0x100a000a8 0x1009c8000 + 229544
9   UIKitCore                              0x1cfe468e0 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 316
10  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe45d8c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2988
11  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe44050 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1092
12  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe43b1c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 108
13  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe405c0 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
14  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe43424 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 220
15  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe431a4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 324
16  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe42704 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 608
17  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe42400 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 248
18  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe40b9c __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
19  UIKitCore                              0x1d08e7670 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
20  UIKitCore                              0x1d09eabb0 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
21  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe40748 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
22  UIKitCore                              0x1d031fc5c __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.243 + 612
23  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe3fbdc -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 208
24  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe3fa54 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
25  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe356f4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 456
26  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe354b4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b5388b3c __95-[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:alternativeCreationCallout:completion:]_block_invoke + 288
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b5389038 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_coalesceClientSettingsUpdates:] + 72
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b5388988 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:alternativeCreationCallout:completion:] + 504
30  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53b5108 __93-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _callOutQueue_sendDidCreateForScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.234 + 284
31  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b536d510 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 196
32  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53b32d8 -[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _callOutQueue_sendDidCreateForScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 512
33  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a8658 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
34  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4ac09c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 284
35  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b536d424 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
36  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53d4374 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
37  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53d44a8 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
38  CoreFoundation                         0x19e742414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
39  CoreFoundation                         0x19e7423a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
40  CoreFoundation                         0x19e74210c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
41  CoreFoundation                         0x19e740cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 840
42  CoreFoundation                         0x19e740334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
43  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b780cc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
44  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b7dd1c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
45  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b7e020 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
46  AppKit                                 0x1a2283a70 _DPSNextEvent + 660
47  AppKit                                 0x1a2ba97b8 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 688
48  AppKit                                 0x1a2276b7c -[NSApplication run] + 480
49  AppKit                                 0x1a224d44c NSApplicationMain + 888
50  AppKit                                 0x1a249b8e4 +[NSWindow _savedFrameFromString:] + 0
51  UIKitMacHelper                         0x1b8ebf8b0 UINSApplicationMain + 972
52  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe1fc40 UIApplicationMain + 148
53  GoQuest                                0x100a25544 0x1009c8000 + 382276
54  dyld                                   0x19e2d8274 start + 2840

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   AppKit                                 0x1a25581fc -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 256
1   AppKit                                 0x1a2557fbc -[NSApplication reportException:] + 460
2   AppKit                                 0x1a27b9990 NSApplicationUncaughtExceptionHandler + 152
3   GoQuest                                0x100b8858c 0x1009c8000 + 1836428
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19e85c7f8 __handleUncaughtException + 816
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19e2a53d8 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19e610710 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19e6106b4 std::terminate() + 108
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a866c _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4ac09c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 284
10  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b536d424 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
11  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53d4374 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
12  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b53d44a8 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
13  CoreFoundation                         0x19e742414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                         0x19e7423a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
15  CoreFoundation                         0x19e74210c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
16  CoreFoundation                         0x19e740cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 840
17  CoreFoundation                         0x19e740334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
18  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b780cc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
19  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b7dd1c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
20  HIToolbox                              0x1a9b7e020 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
21  AppKit                                 0x1a2283a70 _DPSNextEvent + 660
22  AppKit                                 0x1a2ba97b8 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 688
23  AppKit                                 0x1a2276b7c -[NSApplication run] + 480
24  AppKit                                 0x1a224d44c NSApplicationMain + 888
25  AppKit                                 0x1a249b8e4 _NSApplicationMainWithInfoDictionary + 24
26  UIKitMacHelper                         0x1b8ebf8b0 UINSApplicationMain + 972
27  UIKitCore                              0x1cfe1fc40 UIApplicationMain + 148
28  GoQuest                                0x100a25544 0x1009c8000 + 382276
29  dyld                                   0x19e2d8274 start + 2840

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3::  Dispatch queue: com.google.fira.worker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e61bb08 kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4cb5a4 _dispatch_kq_poll + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4caae4 _dispatch_event_loop_poke + 340
3   GoogleUtilities                        0x1011c68b8 -[GULMutableDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 144
4   GoQuest                                0x100ac7434 0x1009c8000 + 1045556
5   GoQuest                                0x100ac7608 0x1009c8000 + 1046024
6   GoQuest                                0x100ac7998 0x1009c8000 + 1046936
7   GoQuest                                0x100ac7c10 0x1009c8000 + 1047568
8   GoQuest                                0x100a406a0 0x1009c8000 + 493216
9   GoQuest                                0x100a82294 0x1009c8000 + 762516
10  GoQuest                                0x100a84524 0x1009c8000 + 771364
11  GoQuest                                0x100a81c78 0x1009c8000 + 760952
12  GoQuest                                0x100ad2b90 0x1009c8000 + 1092496
13  GoQuest                                0x100a40ec8 0x1009c8000 + 495304
14  GoQuest                                0x100a819f0 0x1009c8000 + 760304
15  GoQuest                                0x100a81638 0x1009c8000 + 759352
16  GoQuest                                0x100a80f24 0x1009c8000 + 757540
17  GoQuest                                0x100a80cdc 0x1009c8000 + 756956
18  GoQuest                                0x100a70cb8 0x1009c8000 + 691384
19  GoQuest                                0x100a711e0 0x1009c8000 + 692704
20  GoQuest                                0x100a70524 0x1009c8000 + 689444
21  GoQuest                                0x100a6fd10 0x1009c8000 + 687376
22  GoQuest                                0x100a6f368 0x1009c8000 + 684904
23  GoQuest                                0x100a6f248 0x1009c8000 + 684616
24  GoQuest                                0x100ac7fd4 0x1009c8000 + 1048532
25  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a68f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
26  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a8658 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
27  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4afc60 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 744
28  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4b0768 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
29  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4bb7e8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
30  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4bb034 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 540
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6573d8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4bae18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 0
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6573d8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e619e34 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e62c5d0 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e6229d8 mach_msg_overwrite + 480
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e61a17c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19e7425bc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19e740e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19e740334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   Foundation                             0x19f8fe608 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x19f971b8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 100
9   UIKitCore                              0x1cfe21014 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 104
10  Foundation                             0x19f8f8534 __NSThread__start__ + 724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e65b2e4 _pthread_start + 136
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560fc thread_start + 8

Thread 7::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e61e300 __connect + 8
1   CocoaAsyncSocket                       0x100eb9ea8 __51-[GCDAsyncSocket connectSocket:address:stateIndex:]_block_invoke + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a68f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4a8658 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4ab7a0 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 916
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4ba314 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e4bab20 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e65739c _pthread_wqthread + 228
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 8:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e619e34 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e62c5d0 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e6229d8 mach_msg_overwrite + 480
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19e61a17c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19e7425bc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19e740e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19e740334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   AppKit                                 0x1a23a8bc4 _NSEventThread + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e65b2e4 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560fc thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19e6560e8 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000123064200   x1: 0x00000001230639f5   x2: 0xfffffffffffffff4   x3: 0x0000000123065bd4
    x4: 0xffffffffffffde01   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000123064200   x7: 0x0000000000001a14
    x8: 0x0000000200dc0000   x9: 0xea78fefd992d00be  x10: 0xea78fefd992d00be  x11: 0x000000000000007f
   x12: 0x000000000000005f  x13: 0x000000012482b5e0  x14: 0x0100000202db05b1  x15: 0x0000000202db05b0
   x16: 0x000000019e68fdb0  x17: 0x000000020af6c058  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00006000024585a0
   x20: 0x0000600003f20cc0  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000007  x25: 0x000000000000002f  x26: 0x000000016f435de8  x27: 0x0000000203ef4000
   x28: 0x00000000211200d5   fp: 0x000000016f435ae0   lr: 0x00000001a25581f4
    sp: 0x000000016f435aa0   pc: 0x00000001a25581fc cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0xf2000001 (Breakpoint) brk 1

Binary Images:
       0x1009c8000 -        0x100cdbfff fm.wars.GoQuest (1.5.12) <b8fa47f5-3c46-337a-9938-55c319ec4569> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/GoQuest
       0x100e28000 -        0x100e33fff org.cocoapods.Appirater (1.5.12) <fe60506f-fd60-31d3-be44-c53a7f515ac7> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/Appirater.framework/Appirater
       0x100eb0000 -        0x100ed7fff org.cocoapods.CocoaAsyncSocket (1.5.12) <84a1040a-7ae4-3007-b264-66b1b73d95bb> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework/CocoaAsyncSocket
       0x100e7c000 -        0x100e8bfff org.cocoapods.FBLPromises (1.5.12) <c7b4db40-7165-3933-b915-3aa612750444> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
       0x100f48000 -        0x100f57fff org.cocoapods.FirebaseCore (1.5.12) <c3e9bf4b-52c1-35f5-aade-c52ceae85af9> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore
       0x100fe4000 -        0x100ffffff org.cocoapods.FirebaseCoreInternal (1.5.12) <a984ef26-b3f3-38bd-97f3-631ac583de14> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework/FirebaseCoreInternal
       0x101050000 -        0x101067fff org.cocoapods.FirebaseInstallations (1.5.12) <692a861f-98d6-3a5f-940e-ee5cc1001ed6> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations
       0x10112c000 -        0x10115ffff org.cocoapods.FirebaseMessaging (1.5.12) <a2a4f498-2983-33b6-8aa4-a55d009e5a60> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging
       0x10109c000 -        0x1010bffff org.cocoapods.GoogleDataTransport (1.5.12) <0947959e-6d3e-300e-9774-b9a15805af62> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport
       0x1011bc000 -        0x1011d7fff org.cocoapods.GoogleUtilities (1.5.12) <027b3194-1cc3-3fa6-88f3-40368c146a24> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
       0x100f14000 -        0x100f23fff org.cocoapods.SIAlertView (1.5.12) <dba4ca96-258d-3311-958a-785853f2637f> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/SIAlertView.framework/SIAlertView
       0x100fb0000 -        0x100fc3fff org.cocoapods.SVProgressHUD (1.5.12) <803cef28-2d88-3ec0-b04e-e8dde983368a> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/SVProgressHUD.framework/SVProgressHUD
       0x101294000 -        0x1012c7fff com.twittercore.sdk.ios (1.5.12) <47826d42-615b-3eea-b5ce-dc3dd49302d5> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore
       0x10156c000 -        0x10164bfff com.twitter.sdk.ios (1.5.12) <75aecec2-3b41-3a15-b82a-247b2894d099> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit
       0x100e4c000 -        0x100e53fff org.cocoapods.ionicons (1.5.12) <f0491dce-1318-3a7d-9ac4-d1a5ffaacb15> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/ionicons.framework/ionicons
       0x100e64000 -        0x100e6bfff org.cocoapods.nanopb (1.5.12) <8fff7ac1-9262-3fce-b584-b790cccd7aa8> /private/var/folders/*/GoQuest.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
       0x100f9c000 -        0x100fa7fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib (*) <083ec35f-5279-370a-bdb0-ad21cd9895af> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x10e4b8000 -        0x10eb53fff com.apple.AGXMetal13-3 (320.35.5) <ddf75840-d4dc-3f8b-b2cd-aa6f43afe4de> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXMetal13_3.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AGXMetal13_3
       0x1a2249000 -        0x1a361dfff com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <e02a6094-92a9-3418-a312-a1fbaf4f477b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
       0x19e6c4000 -        0x19ebbafff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <90eb8fd1-925e-38eb-a056-eb4253b6a29e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x19e280000 -        0x19e2d1cb3 libobjc.A.dylib (*) <f453c5ae-3568-3aaa-aaa0-d2fdfbb9bc7a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x19e5fe000 -        0x19e618fff libc++abi.dylib (*) <676af2e8-ec78-3e6e-8275-2130fefcfe8e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
       0x19e4a4000 -        0x19e4eafff libdispatch.dylib (*) <465565e8-ef8a-3188-80fa-598063c54161> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1b5368000 -        0x1b5433fff com.apple.FrontBoardServices (943.1.1) <d3c3c6cb-bedb-385e-a254-f9ed89a35c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/Versions/A/FrontBoardServices
       0x1a9a6c000 -        0x1a9d73fff com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1) <66acb183-62b9-3856-82a9-07c05dc29bcc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
       0x1b8ebb000 -        0x1b8fd4fff com.apple.UIKitMacHelper (1.0) <07324457-7582-37ad-b3ca-fff1d06f57f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitMacHelper.framework/Versions/A/UIKitMacHelper
       0x1cfe1c000 -        0x1d1b22fff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) <0399bf5c-6557-3ac6-86e4-542ce59dd4da> /System/iOSSupport/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/Versions/A/UIKitCore
       0x19e2d2000 -        0x19e354663 dyld (*) <02e3ca05-e849-31c8-a4f2-c7292420dfad> /usr/lib/dyld
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x19e68c000 -        0x19e693fe3 libsystem_platform.dylib (*) <3fac373b-5c41-3c83-8f9f-c9e781e887da> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x19e654000 -        0x19e660fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <d09f4078-adad-3dd0-b17b-ce0142887b28> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x19e619000 -        0x19e653ff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <9a72fd37-d827-3d6d-b6f4-422621e36c94> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x19f8a4000 -        0x1a06f1fff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <ca2d8817-b530-31d5-beed-18991a27afc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"GoQuest","timestamp":"2024-09-30 19:24:19.00 -0400","app_version":"1.5.12","slice_uuid":"b8fa47f5-3c46-337a-9938-55c319ec4569","adam_id":"834841918","build_version":"1.5.12.0","platform":2,"bundleID":"fm.wars.GoQuest","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 15.0 (24A335)","roots_installed":0,"name":"GoQuest","incident_id":"E6B1583F-AB66-4F64-A03B-F3EA3CD533FB"}
{
  "uptime" : 180000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "Macmini9,1",
  "coalitionID" : 2338,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 15.0",
    "build" : "24A335",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2024-09-30 19:24:16.0923 -0400",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 1,
  "incident" : "E6B1583F-AB66-4F64-A03B-F3EA3CD533FB",
  "pid" : 78282,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2024-09-30 19:24:15.2960 -0400",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 4513460941179,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 4513479916505,
  "procName" : "GoQuest",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/folders\/*\/GoQuest.app\/GoQuest",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.5.12","CFBundleVersion":"1.5.12.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"fm.wars.GoQuest","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"storeCohortMetadata":"10|date=1697284800000&sf=143455&pgtp=Search&pgid=ios&prpg=Search_ios&ctxt=Search&issrch=1&imptyp=card&kind=iosSoftware&lngid=6","itemID":"834841918","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"3DD89811-BA1F-5D06-9EEA-84F6B2BD91F2","softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"856908199","thirdParty":true,"applicationVariant":"1:MacFamily20,1:15"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "fm.wars.GoQuest",
  "crashReporterKey" : "4C73C89D-D754-81CA-E621-DB60C76F9BE8",
  "codeSigningID" : "fm.wars.GoQuest",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "TR45WGVQZV",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570454785,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 4294967295,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"AAArkWgg+pfgAxOq6BtBlILrMNBCACmRFTFBlMw3P5RIQy+QAIEB+Q==","atPC":"IAAg1PMDAKrhAQA04AMTqvN6LZT\/AwD5AACA0lgg+pcPey2UIAAg1A=="},
  "bootSessionUUID" : "B2FAB831-D3DD-4F0B-BA56-9754EF48ACFA",
  "wakeTime" : 9245,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "BFC1F86B-870C-4ABA-9C79-745C6BC50E54",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a25581fc","rawCodes":[1,7018480124],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":78282},
  "os_fault" : {"process":"GoQuest"},
  "exceptionReason" : {"arguments":["__NSCFData","componentsSeparatedByString:","0x6000024593e0"],"format_string":"-[%s %s]: unrecognized selector sent to instance %p","name":"NSInvalidArgumentException","type":"objc-exception","composed_message":"-[__NSCFData componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000024593e0","class":"NSException"},
  "asiBacktraces" : ["0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e7b4ec0 __exceptionPreprocess + 176\n1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019e29acd8 objc_exception_throw + 88\n2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e86a5a4 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0\n3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e721140 ___forwarding___ + 1568\n4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e720a60 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96\n5   GoQuest                             0x00000001009f4b40 GoQuest + 183104\n6   GoQuest                             0x00000001009f472c GoQuest + 182060\n7   GoQuest                             0x00000001009f4674 GoQuest + 181876\n8   GoQuest                             0x0000000100a000a8 GoQuest + 229544\n9   UIKitCore                                         


I don’t have a solid answer, but for sure, this is something that reporting crashes to Apple and to developers as an opt in is the best way for them to know this is happening. It will be challenging to understand if GoQuest is using Apple SDK wrong, or the SDK have bugs needing fixed…

@bmike I have opted in to submitting crash reports and I can't find a way myself to write to the company (Mindwalk Corp) to let them know. I was kind of hoping that someone would give me some related processes to kill.  Anyway with iPhone mirroring, I can just play that way on my computer when I inevitably close the app.

Understood - even if their App Store support page is great, it might not get a clear answer your way. It sure does crash fast, maybe someone here knows how to clear the app translocation folder (/private/var/folders/…) between launches?

First, I see in the Mac App Store that this iOS app, although available, is "not verified for macOS." From my experience, that usually means it won't be fully functional on Macs.
That said, I also see from your crash report that the app is running translocated. For a somewhat opaque explanation of what that means, see:

App Translocation Notes (forums.developer.apple.com)

Or for a clearer explanation:

What causes App Translocation? (eclecticlight.co)

That should only happen the first time it runs, unless the quarantine attribute fails to be removed for some reason. You can remove the attribute yourself by running the following shell command in Terminal:
sudo xattr -c -r /Applications/GoQuest.app

Here I'm assuming that the app is installed in the Applications folder and is named exactly "GoQuest".
This may not make any difference, but there's no harm in trying.

Thanks.  It didn't work.  The app runs flawlessly when it does run so I do think it's a simple thing like this that makes it crash.  Well I'm just gonna restart my Mac and go back to being careful not to close the app.
